# Matlab: Put a sum into a function

Tags: matlab, function, octave

I would like to approximate numerical data by a function:

```
f = @(a0,xdata) a0(1).*xdata + ... + a0(n) .* xdata.^n
```

How can I do that, since a for loop does not work in a function? I know there is an internal polynomial function, but since I might want to extend the sum to non-integer exponents, I want to write my own function.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a series ie `f = @(a0,xdata) a0(1)*xdata.^(n-1) + a0(2)*xdata.^(n-2) + ... + a0(n)`? Otherwise, I'm not sure what `...` is

Comment: “a for loop does not work in a function” Of course it does! Just not in an anonymous function. Write a real function!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f = @(a0,xdata) sum(a0 .* xdata.^(1:length(a0)));
```

If you insist on writing this as anonymous function, but I'd recommend writing this as a function on multiple lines with a function body:

```
function out = f(a0,xdata)
    exponents = 1:length(a0);
    out = sum(a0 .*xdata .^ exponents);
end
```